# Spring MVC Dynamic Data Table/Grid inside a form using Jquery

Tags: jquery, spring

My Requirement is,

1.I have a form, bind with one model Attribute - on submit on am getting my model object with data

2.Now I have a data table and input fields of all columns of that table,with its Save button ->inside my  main form

3.Now I want to add/remove records to my table - **and on final submit of Form**, it will go to my controller with all records, also I have list of object of the table with my Main model attribute.

Please help me how to implement this dynamic table inside the form,share the code or any related links.

Thanks for your help

Comment: http://www.dynatable.com/

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Not yet, looks like it is impossible.Really strange, we only have such requirement.requirement. Initially thinking it is a common requirement.